# payload is null from server

Tags: android, titanium

In my app receives the **push notification from GCM**(for android) everything is fine am getting the notification but the payload is null. Cross checked server side script it's fine. This is the response am getting in callback method

This is the GCM response

```
{"type":"callback", 
 "source":{"pushType":"gcm", "invocationAPIs":[],
 "showAppOnTrayClick":true, 
 singleCallback":false, 
 "__propertiesDefined__":true, 
 "bubbleParent":true, 
 "_events":{"callback":{}, 
 "trayClickLaunchedApp":{}, 
 "trayClickFocusedApp":{}}, 
 "focusAppOnPush":false, 
 "enabled":false, 
 "showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused":false, 
 "apiName":"Ti.Module", 
 "showTrayNotification":true,"debug":false},
 "payload":"","bubbles":false, 
 "cancelBubble":false}
```

Am using **Titanium 3.5.1GA** and tried with **ti.cloudpush(3.3.7)** same issues .

How can i solve it?

Comment: i have used pushsharp libraary from server side

Answer (score 0):

Since the notification does arrive it's probably not an error in the app but on the server sending the payload. Try one of the several (online) apps to test notifications on Google.